# How to prevent windows from changing external display virtual desktop when I change primary display virtual desktop?

Tags: multiple-monitors, window, virtual-desktop

I have a 2 screen setup and I use virtual desktop on windows 10.

When I change from virtual desktop 1 to virtual desktop 2 in Display1, it also changes on display2.

It there a way to prevent this behavior?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible with the standard Windows 10 built-in virtual desktops. I'm pretty sure it's possible with third-party virtual desktop programs however.

Answer (score 7):

This will be possible in Windows 10 Version 21H2.

In that version you will find in
*Settings > System > Multitasking* the additional option of
"Displays have separate virtual desktops":

[image]

For more information, see the article
[Windows 10 21H2 (Sun Valley): 5 big changes coming to Settings](https://pureinfotech.com/windows-10-21h2-sun-valley-changes-settings/).

Edit : The year is 2023 and Microsoft has perhaps abandoned
this feature.

Comment: is this feature also available in windows 11 21H2? 
I can find it

Comment: I don't have multiple displays, so cannot test it. This option doesn't show up in my Windows 10 21H2, and neither in my Windows 11 VM, but this could possibly be because I have only one monitor.

Comment: Windows 11 Pro 21H2 here with multiple monitors, I can confirm this isn't implemented.

Comment: This feature by Microsoft missed the deadline. It might hopefully come-in sometime later.

Comment: It is still not in Windows 11 10.0.22621 Build 22621. If it were in windows 10 and not in windows 11, then it is a big step back.

Comment: It's not there in windows 10 pro 22H2. Is there anyway to enable this settings without downgrading?